# leer de archivo par de valores a mapa

Tags: java

Si tengo este archivo .txt de:

```
 Ciudad de Partida|Ciudad,Distancia|Ciudad,Distancia|...|Ciudad,Distancia 
 Pedernales|Ambato,318|Azogues,555
 Ambato|Azogues,280|Babahoyo,212|...|Pedernales,318
 Azogues| Pedernales,555|...|Babahoyo,125
 ..
 Babahoyo|Ambato,250
```

¿Cómo hago este método?

> a. cargarDatos(nombreArchivo) que recibe el nombre del archivo como string 
>        y retorna el diccionario distancias con el siguiente formato:
>         {‘Ambato’:{‘Azogues’:280, ‘Babahoyo’:212, … ,‘Pedernales’:318}, … 
>         {‘Babahoyo’:{‘Ambato’:250}}}

Tengo hasta ahora esto pero no estoy segura de cómo concluir:

```
public static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> cargarDatos(String archivo) {
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> mapa = new HashMap();
    LinkedList<String> lista = new LinkedList();
    try {
        File f = new File(archivo);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String linea = s.nextLine();
            String[] datos = linea.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
                String[] d = datos[i].split(",");
                mapa.put(datos[0],);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("El archivo no existe...");
    }

    return mapa;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el criterio que se toma en cuenta para arrojar ese resultado? ¿Las claves son ciudades de partida?

Comment: sí, las claves son ciudades de partida, y los valores son otro diccionario con las ciudades de llegada y sus respectivas distancias.

Comment: funcionó perfectamente :D muchas gracias. no me separaba bien al inicio porque solo hacia .split("|") no se me habría ocurrido poner antes los slash ("\\|")

Comment: Perfecto Michelle, si es necesario escapar ese carácter ya que `split` toma expresiones regulares y **|**  tiene un significado que es `OR` . Saludos.

Comment: me podrías ayudar con un ejercicio de listas anidadas? @Dev.Joel

Comment: si agrega su pregunta de que se trata , igual puede recibir ayuda no solo de mi parte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iba por buen camino. Solo tendría que utilizar correctamente `split` para obtener las distancias, además cree una variable temporal `HashMap` para las ciudades de llegada. *(La mayoría del código está comentado)*

```
public static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> cargarDatos(String archivo) {
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> mapa = new HashMap();

    try {
        File f = new File(archivo);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        String[] dist ;//Variable temporal
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String linea = s.nextLine();
            // El split , es necesario escapar el | ya que es un OR
            String[] datos = linea.split("\\|");
            // Variable temporal para almacenar las ciudades y distancias
            HashMap<String,Integer> distancias = new HashMap<>();
            //Iteramos a partir de la seunda columna , ya que la primera
            // será la clave del map
            for (int i = 1; i < datos.length; i++) {
                // separamos las distancias y ciudades
               dist = datos[i].split(",");
               // y añadimos al map
               distancias.put(dist[0], Integer.parseInt(dist[1]));
            }
            //la primera será la clave del map
            mapa.put(datos[0], distancias);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("El archivo no existe...");
    }

    return mapa;
}
```